# How to template a parameter in function pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, function-pointers, function-templates

I have a template:

```
template<typename T>
void testFuction(int(*testFunc)(CallBack, void *, T *))
{
    // define CallBack callback, void* param1, T* param2
    // ...
    testFunc(callback, param1, param2);
}
```

It works but it looks terrible,
I want to do something like:

```
template<typename T>
// using TestFunc<T> = std::function<int(CallBack, void *, T *)>
void testFuction(TestFunc<T> testFunc)
{
   // define CallBack callback, void* param1, T* param2
   // ...
   testFunc(callback, param1, param2);
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Can somebody help me with it? 
I also overload many similar functions like that with some added parameters and they look ugly.
I want to define `TestFunc<T>` once and use it again in the template functions.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Maybe you need an alias template first, `template <typename T> using TestFunc = std::function<(int(Callback, void*, T*)>;`?

Comment: compiler said 
`no matching function for call to 'VendorTester::testFuction(int (&)(CallBack, void*, SomeData*))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide a type alias for the templated function pointer as follows

```
#include <utility> // std::forward

template<typename T>
using FunPointerT = int(*)(CallBack, void*, T*);

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void testFuction(FunPointerT<T> funcPtr, Args&& ...args)
{
   // variadic args, in the case of passing args to testFuction
   funcPtr(std::forward<Arg>(args)...);
}
```

Update as per Op's requirement

```
template<typename T> 
void testFuction(FunPointerT<T> funcPtr) 
{
   // ...
   funcPtr(/* args from local function scope */);
}
```

Comment: No, I didn't intend for forward parameter, my compiler said `no matching function for call to 'VendorTester::testFuction(int (&)(CallBack, void*, SomeData*))`
`vendorTester.testFunction(SomeFunctionToBeTest);`

Comment: Eventhough they have same parameters

Comment: I have to use alias without std::function<>, thank you JeJo

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at a simplified example:

```cpp
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
void test_function(std::function<void(T*)> f) {
    f(nullptr);
}

void use_int_ptr(int* i);

int main() {
    test_function(use_int_ptr);
}
```

Which fails to compile: `T` can't be deduced as `int`. The reason it works with `void (*f)(T*)` is that `T` *can* be deduced if passed a function pointer, but a function pointer isn't a `std::function`.

You have a few possible solutions. You could manually specify `T`:

```cpp
test_function<int>(use_int_ptr);
```

You could pass a `std::function` instead so that `T` can be deduced:

```cpp
test_function(std::function<void(int*)>{use_int_ptr});
// Or in C++17 with CTAD
test_function(std::function{use_int_ptr});
```

Make a forwarding function that wraps function pointers in `std::function`s as above, needing to manually pass `std::function`s for other callables:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void test_function(void f(T*)) {
    test_function(std::function<void(T*)>{f});
}
```

Or simply take any type in your original function:

```cpp
template<typename F>
void test_function(F&& f) {
    f(nullptr);
}
```